# How to include a library using CMAKE in a cross-platform way

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

I am trying to use the [assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/tools/assimp_view/CMakeLists.txt) library in a cross platform C++ project.  I include the repo as a git submodule, so, effectively, if someone downloads my project they will also download the ASSIMP project.

After I go through the assimp build / CMAKE instructions and (on Linux) type `make install` and from then on in my project I can use:

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)`

However, there is no `make install` on Windows.

The only other way I have been able to include the library on Linux is to put (in my `CmakeLists.txt` file):

`target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/assimp/code/libassimp.so)`

This is not cross platform as it hardcodes the name and location of the `.so` file which will not work on Windows.

How can I expose the library so that I can do something like `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp)` on all platforms?

My directory tree looks like:

```
- src
- include
    - assimp
- bin
```

Where the `assimp` directory in the `include` directory is the git submodule

Comment: I would start with `find_package()` especially since assimp is built using `CMake`.

Comment: Well it does have an `install` target.  If you built on Windows with MinGW `make install` should work. The same thing with `Visual Studio`.  Or you can use `fetch_content` to build it and just use `find_package()`. Kind of depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. You don't need to build assimp in a separate step from your project, and you don't need to `make install` to make it available.

There are a number of ways of handling third party dependencies in Cmake, since you've already chosen to submodule the assimp repository, we'll start there. Assuming assimp is located in the root of your repository in a directory called `assimp/` this would be a barebones project including it:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(Project myassimpproj)

# include your directories
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  )

# set any variables you might need to set for your app and assimp
set(BUILD_ASSIMP_TOOLS  ON)
set(ASSIMP_BUILD_STATIC_LIB ON)

# add assimp source dir as a subdirectory, effectively making 
# assimp's CMakeLists.txt part of your build
add_subdirectory(/path/to/assimp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/assimp)

add_executable(assimp_target main.cpp)

# be sure to link in assimp, use platform-agnostic syntax for the linker
target_link_libraries(assimp_target assimp)
```

There may be a better way of phrasing this using generator expressions syntax, but I haven't looked at assimp's CMakeLists.txt to know if it's supported (and this is a more generic way anyway.)

Not every project uses Cmake, so you may not be able to just `add_subdirectory()`. In those cases, you can effectively "fake" a user call to build them using their build commands on respective platforms. `execute_process()` runs a command at configure time `add_custom_command()` and `add_custom_target()` run commands at build time. You then create a fake target to make integration and cross your fingers they support Cmake someday.

You can also use the [`ExternalProject`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) commands added to Cmake to create a custom target to drive download, update/patch, configure, build, install and test steps of an external project, but note that this solution and the next download the dependency rather than using the submodule'd source code.

Finally, I prefer to work with prebuilt dependencies, cuts down on build time, and they can be unit tested on their own outside of the project. [Conan](https://conan.io) is an open source, decentralized and multi-platform package manager with very good support for C++ and almost transparent support for Cmake when used the right way. They have grown very stable in the last year. More information on how to use Conan with Cmake can be found [here](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/integrations/cmake.html).

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason for `include_directories(assimp/include/ )`.  The target `assimp` should already be using `target_include_directories(PUBLIC)` to setup the include path. It'll just happen auto-magically.

Comment: Updated to reflect that. Old habits die hard. Been using CMake for ages, but since my example sets a minimum version of 3.0, you are absolutely correct.

Comment: I get `cmake_minimum_required called with unknown argument "3.0".`

Comment: Can you explain what the `assimppro` variable is?

Comment: I also get the following error: `CMake Error at src/projects/3d_model/CMakeLists.txt:28 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
  directory
  "/home/user/Documents/projects/dsa_opengl_examples/include/assimp" is
  not a subdirectory of
  "/home/user/Documents/projects/dsa_opengl_examples/src/projects/3d_model".
  When specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly
  specified.
`

Comment: @Startec That error happens when you use `add_subdirectory(srcdir)` and `srcdir` isn't actually a subdirectory of the project.  The directory tree that you are using wasn't posted.  In this case you need to do `add_subdirectory(/path/to/assimp ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/assimp)` to specify a binary directory for the `assimp` files.

Comment: @Startec `assimppro` isn't a variable its just a target name.  It's just an example of how a target can link against `assimp`.

Comment: @Fred thanks for the clarification.  What is the difference between the first argument (which is the path to assimp and the second one `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/assimp` which is not a real directory (see my updated directory tree.

Comment: @Startec `cmake` will create the directory `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/assimp` to store the project files for that target.  The first argument is the source location of the `CMakeLists.txt`.  The second argument is the binary folder to store the project files and binary outputs.  Because the source directory tree is non-standard `cmake` can not automatically determine the layout of the binary directory tree.

Comment: Updated example to reflect this